# Create PHP request script

Tags: php

so i want to run a service which will check new emails every "n" minutes from the database and send to intended receivers. this is what i can think of so far:

> services.php

```
set_time_limit(0);

$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), true);

header("Connection: close");
header("Content-length: " . (string) ob_get_length());
ob_end_flush();

if (@$data["op"] == "1min") {
    
    EmailQueue();
}
if (@$data["op"] == "5min") {
    
    SMSQueue();
}
```

as you can see from the above code there are two conditions to be applied based on data stream set on another script. so my question is, how can i create another script which can send stream of request to services.php simultaneously so that function EmailQueue and SMSQueue run every 1min and 5min respectively? note that i want to run the request from 1 script. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should use cron-job or services like IFTTT, Zapier, Automate.io etc...

Comment: Does this mean I have to create different scripts for each functions?

Comment: No, I think you have to create a simple *webhook* and call it every X minutes using cron-job or one of the (free) services I've mentioned above (there are many others).

Comment: as you can see my question is to get some example on creating script which calls each conditions on different X minutes.

Answer (score 0):

You should use cron job for that

Comment: This should probably be posted as a comment and not an answer

Comment: @dazed-and-confused I am not allowed to post comments - yet